# How can I add multiple products in "add to cart" page of asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, listview

I am making a website in which when customer click on add to cart button,then particular product and it's details should display on add to cart page, as I have mentioned below code by using this I can show only one product and it's details.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblProductDetails where ProductId=" + PId, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        productcartlistview.DataSource = ds;
        productcartlistview.DataBind();
```

and by using hidden field I am getting product id.

```
    Button btn_AddCart = sender as Button;
    HiddenField myhiddenfield =btn_AddCart.NamingContainer.FindControl("hiddenID") as HiddenField;
    int myID = Convert.ToInt32(myhiddenfield.Value);

    Response.Redirect("CartPage.aspx?ProdId=" + myID + "");
```

So when I want to add another product, then it has been replaced by new one. I want to show multiple products and their details in listview.How can I do this? Please help me .
Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in session, viewbag may be.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to maintain the state of the user session in this case.** By maintaining the state, I mean to say you need to continously maintain what procducts he/she is adding to his cart or deleting them or changing the quantity or things like that.

For this you will have to make use of some state persisting components available in the .NET Framework.

Like you have mentioned that the existing product is getting replaced by the new one, to avoid this, you will have to make use of *state persisting objects such as Session or Application state or Cookies or Ultimately Database etc.* Its your choice based on the type of requirements you have.

Just for an example in your case, lets say everytime the user performs the add to cart event, you make a `List` object and store the product IDs in it and keep adding new IDs whenever the user adds a new product. And you store the List in `Session`.

I would recommend you go through this article which is quite nice for understanding state management concepts for both client side and server side state management.

[Client side and server side state management techniques](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)